# Array to string conversion $log user, yii2

Tags: arrays, yii2

im going to implementation RBAC on yii2 and already added role and permission for user, but when login i got this errors

> Array to string conversion

```
 * @return bool whether the user is logged in
 */
public function login(IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0)
{
    if ($this->beforeLogin($identity, false, $duration)) {
        $this->switchIdentity($identity, $duration);
        $id = $identity->getId();
        $ip = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP();
        if ($this->enableSession) {
```

> ```
>  $log = "User '$id' logged in from $ip with duration $duration.";
> ```

```
        } else {
            $log = "User '$id' logged in from $ip. Session not enabled.";
        }
        Yii::info($log, __METHOD__);
        $this->afterLogin($identity, false, $duration);
    }

    return !$this->getIsGuest();
}
```

please advance help me to solve this problem

Comment: i found solution is i dunno why my db 'user' doesnt have primary key on id, and i add primary on it then the errors gone, CLOSED

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem, and after I read your comment, I found my solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

On your user table make sure id is the primary key, In my case it was not by default